# Problem with deploying to Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, vue.js, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy my app to Google Cloud, but I still receive error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
> biurovue@1.0.0 start /app
> node build/dev-server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'chalk' .....
```

My app is built with nodejs, back end is in Express and Sequalizer and front end is in vuejs.
I'm calling

```
gcloud int
gcloud app deploy
```

and then, after few minutes error above occures.
I've tried several times:

```
npm install chalk
```

also, I've removed node_modules folder and call `npm install` from the scratch. Didn't help.

My package.json is following:

```
{
"name": "biurovue",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A Vue.js project",
"author": "Shark <arek.shark@gmail.com>",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
"start": "node build/dev-server.js",
"build": "node build/build.js",
"unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js -- single-run",
"e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
"test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
},
"dependencies": {
"@okta/jwt-verifier": "0.0.11",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"each-async": "^1.1.1",
"easy-async": "^1.0.0",
"finale-rest": "^1.0.6",
"indent-string": "^4.0.0",
"sequelize": "^4.37.6",
"sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuedraggable": "^2.23.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^7.1.5",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.5",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
"babel-register": "^6.26.0",
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"chalk": "^2.4.2",
"chromedriver": "^2.33.1",
"connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.4.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
"cross-env": "^5.0.5",
"cross-spawn": "^5.1.0",
"css-loader": "^0.28.7",
"cssnano": "^3.10.0",
"eslint": "^4.9.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
"eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
"eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"file-loader": "^1.1.5",
"friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
"http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
"inject-loader": "^3.0.1",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.5.0",
"karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.2",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.5",
"mocha": "^4.0.1",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
"opn": "^5.1.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"ora": "^1.3.0",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15",
"rimraf": "^2.6.2",
"selenium-server": "^3.6.0",
"semver": "^5.4.1",
"shelljs": "^0.7.8",
"sinon": "^4.0.1",
"sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
"sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
"uglify-es": "^3.1.3",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2",
"vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
"vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
"webpack": "^3.7.1",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">= 4.0.0",
"npm": ">= 3.0.0"
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not ie <= 8"
]
}
```

What can be a problem? How to solve? diagnose errors like this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you show package.json?

Comment: noice, ok, locally run `npm ci  --only=prod` then what errors out, move them libs into "dependencies" section, express should definitely not be in devDependencies

Comment: I've run this comman, but I have no errors, only several node-pre-gyp info and one node-pre-gyp WARN, what exactly shall I do with this output? Thanks

Comment: does your app start after?

Comment: When I call npm run dev, I receive an error: "Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'", should I move shelljs from devDependencies to dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Move them into `dependencies`. `devDependencies` should really only be used, as its name suggests, for development. Suppose you have a package which in turn has multiple dependencies. Suppose you are using `mochaJS`, `chaiJS` and `sinonJS` to achieve full test coverage. The end-user installing your package most likely wouldn't want to install the testing and/or documentation frameworks you used as well. Thus, those frameworks would be placed on `devDependencies`. In this case, because `chalk` and `shellJS` are required **at runtime** they would have to be placed in `dependencies`.

> Summary: Use `dependencies` for packages required **at runtime** and `devDependencies` for packages required only to develop ( testing frameworks, linting, etc. )

Comment: Thanks, but having so many dependencies and relation between them, how can I know witch of them should I move from devDependencies to dependencies.

Comment: No worries, reiterating what I said above, `use dependencies for packages required **at runtime**`. As a general rule of thumb (with some exceptions of course), any package you `require` or `import` somewhere in your code should be placed in `dependencies`. To be more specific, if running `npm start` (runtime) uses a certain package, place it in `dependencies`. In any case, I would suggest giving the following articles a read to give you a more in-depth look on this topic.

Comment: [Medium](https://medium.com/@stalonadsl948/dependencies-vs-devdependencies-926e096a3dee) [dev.to](https://dev.to/moimikey/demystifying-devdependencies-and-dependencies-5ege)